# Finding eigenvalues of given matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

$A = \left(\begin{array}{ccc}0 & -1 & 0 \\0 & 0 & 1 \\-1 & -3 & 3\end{array}\right)$

I want to find eigenvalues of this matrix.

The answer given to me is: 1,1,1.

I cannot arrive at that answer. I get complex numbers for my eigenvalues.

Am I doing something wrong? Is there a way to get 1,1,1 as your eigenvalues?

Answer (score 3):

Calculate the characteristic polynomial, $\det|sI-A|$, 
$$\det\left(\begin{array}{ccc}s & 1 & 0 \\0 & s & -1 \\1 & 3 & s-3\end{array}\right)=s(s(s-3)+3)-1(1)=s^3-3s^2+3s-1=(s-1)^3$$
The three eigenvalues are the roots of this polynomial, and hence are all equal to $1$.

Answer (score 2):

The [eigenvalues](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors) can be obtained by equating the determinant of $A-\lambda I$ to zero.
$$
\det(A-\lambda I)=
\left|
\begin{array}{ccc}
-\lambda & -1 & 0 \\
0 & -\lambda & 1 \\
-1 & -3 & 3-\lambda
\end{array}
\right|=
\lambda^2(3-\lambda)+1-3\lambda=(1-\lambda)^3
$$

Hence they are given by the solutions of $(1-\lambda)^3=0$

Comment: For future reference: 
$$
\begin{vmatrix} 1&2\\3&4 \end{vmatrix}
$$
can be coded as `\begin{vmatrix} 1&2\\3&4 \end{vmatrix}`.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Great thanks :)